# ionic3 - text auto play (horizontal and loop)

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

example: https://github.com/bingcool/ionic-banner-tips,
Please open the link and check, I want it like same top of the screen that yellow text can auto horizontal scroll and loop.

[image]

Edit:

```
  <ion-slides autoplay="1" loop="true" speed="3000">
    <ion-slide>This is the loop text</ion-slide>
  </ion-slides>
```

This is my project, I want my ionic3 project same like that example the yellow one. And make the text in one line.
[image]

Comment: Your git link seems `Ionic 1` no?

Comment: That's not me.. that one is ionic1 project plugin.. but I want same function in ionci3.. I think "ion-slides" can solved this problem

Comment: @Sampath please check my code please

Comment: Is that working?

Comment: yes.. I screenshot the picture is my project.. at the top of the picture is the text which I want it to auto scope

Comment: If it is working then what is your issue?

Comment: Problem soled thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally problem solved

**html file**
[image]

**scss file**

```
.a {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: pink;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.b {
    position: absolute;
    width: 1440px;
    height: 100%;
}
.b p {
    // width: 480px;
    // height: 100%;
    margin-left: 400px;
    float: left;
}
.play {
    animation: ma 10s 3s infinite linear;
}
@keyframes ma {
    0% {
        margin-left: 0px;
    }
    100% {
        margin-left: -1200px;
    }
}
.play:hover {
    animation-play-state: paused;
}
```

Final project screenshot
[image]